# how to use more element in listview? 

Tags: java, android

i m new to android .

i m doing my final yr project in android.

Is the any way to use more elements in list view control....

for example: fetch more data frm database and add it at runtime. 
 the formate may be

---

text    text

text     text

---

text    text

text     text

---

etc.....

refer this page for model https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.diaryfree&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImFwcC5kaWFyeWZyZWUiXQ..

(in this page sample image for that application wil be given, like that report i need to display my data.)

is  any other control there for that??? how to add runtime more assign more than one element value???

like this

and how to find which row is clicked?

thankz in advance

Answer (score 1):

you can create custom list views to format the listview the way you asked for. And cursors are a good way to fetch data from a database and pass it to a listview. you can use adapters for that.

a sample code for custom list view can be seen [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/bosuch/archive/2011/01/31/android---create-a-custom-multi-line-listview-bound-to-an.aspx)

to find out which item is clicked you need to use onListItemClickListener like given here [Android: onListItemClick in Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080165/android-onlistitemclick-in-activity)

Comment: can u give sample program for that?? and also i want to know which row is clicked ..

Comment: edited the answer to what you asked for. i hope it helps you.

Comment: also do remember to accept the answer close the thread if all your questions are answered so that others can refer to it.

Comment: @ Anurag Ramdasan thax for ur kindly respose